# What are the differences between @nrwl/web:webpack and webpack?

Tags: webpack, monorepo

I'm starting to configure my project using `Nx` and `webpack`. I can not understand the use of `Nx` executers at all. What is the benefit of using `@nrwl/web:webpack` instead of `webpack`? All I understand is it's just a layer of abstraction over `webpack`. Are there any performance optimizations or something? Isn't it better to use `webpack` directly since it is simpler to configure and does not have any extra abstractions?